# How to use Oracle Timestamp while doing insert/update in Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SomeTable")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "MODIFIED")
  private Timestamp modifiedDt;
}
```

How should I instruct "modifiedDt" to use oracle timestamp whenever there is a insert/update operation ?

Provided there would be no trigger or something similar to be done on the DB side for the Table.

I tried below but no luck,

```
@Column(name = "TS_MODIFIED", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just define the column to update the value to the current timestamp when a row is updated, like this:

`CREATE TABLE SomeTable(
  MODIFIED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);`

[For more information see the Oracle docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: So, there has to be DDL changes to the table. I need to know there is no other way without touching the table to do this entirely from Java.

Comment: Sorry, that gives error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` on Oracle 12c.

Comment: Hmmm, the example is straight from the Oracle docs. I only changed the table and column name to match the example from @Vis.  Perhaps 'MODIFIED' is a reserved word and can't be used as a column name on Oracle 12c?

Comment: Thanks. But, DB team is not ready to make changes to the tables. I somehow convinced to use application timestamp generated by Java. Trying PreUpdate and PrePersist.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Entity Listener. See the Hibernate manual [chapter 6, "Entity listeners and callback methods"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

In your case, you probably want to apply and implement the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` callbacks. Something like...

```
@Entity
//...

   @PreUpdate
   @PrePersist
   private void doSetModified() {
      this.modifiedDt = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that already but @Pre**** method is not getting called.